# How to handle events such as onClick for own Components in Next.JS and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, event-handling, tailwind-css

I use tailwindCSS for styling, and the code is written in Typescript using Next.JS.

I have written a generic "Button" component to be re-used throughout my platform. If the button gets pressed from wherever it is used, I want to be able to update its UI in some way. For example, if the action being carried out takes a while to load, I want to add a spinner inside the button so that the user knows that the button has been pressed and their request is being processed.

However, of course I also want to execute whichever action that button corresponds to. For example, if the button is used on the Login page, a function will be called to try to login in the user.

Therefore, the way I see it, I would have to execute two functions when the button is pressed:
1- Inside Button.tsx (component), I want to execute a function that "shows" the spinner and adds opacity to the actual <button> contained within.
2- Execute a function in login.tsx (page) which handles the login logic.

I am new to React/Next and am not sure if this is the correct approach or not. My Button looks like this:

```
interface ButtonProps {
    primary?: boolean;
    backgroundColor?: string;
    size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
    label: string;
    styling: string;
    type: string;
    onClick?: () => void;
}

let main_btn = "bg-main text-white hover:bg-transparent hover:text-main"
let secondary_btn = "bg-transparent text-main hover:bg-main hover:text-white"

let sm = 'py-[0.25rem] px-[0.5rem] text-sm'
let md = 'py-[0.375rem] px-[0.75rem] text-base'
let lg = 'py-[0.5rem] px-[0.1rem] text-lg'

const Button = ({primary = false, size = 'medium', backgroundColor, label, type, styling, ...props}: ButtonProps) => {
    const mode = primary ? main_btn : secondary_btn;
    const sz = size == "medium" ? md : size == "small" ? sm : lg;
    return (
        <button
            type="button"
            className={`${sz} rounded ${mode} w-full text-center border border-main hover:cursor-pointer ${styling}`}
            style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor, 'borderColor': backgroundColor }}
            onClick={() => {
                switch(type) {
                    case "load":
                        //When button has been clicked and processing takes a while add spinner
                        break;
                    case "disable":
                        //If button is disabled for whatever reason add opacity
                        break;
                }
                props.onClick;
            }}
            {...props}>
            {label}
        </button>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

And the Button being used might look like this:

```
<Button label="Iniciar sesión" primary={true} size="medium" styling="mb-8" type="load" onClick={loggingin} />
```

However, either the "loggingin" function from the login page is called or the code inside the Button component is called, not both. How can I execute some code inside the Component each time that there is an onClick event, while also executing the required logic from where the Button component is being used (login page)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the OP is still looking for an answer, but in the event someone else ends up here and is looking for a solution, here is a working example.  In the OPs version, the provided callback was not properly called.

button.tsx

```
interface ButtonProps {
  primary?: boolean;
  backgroundColor?: string;
  size?: "small" | "medium" | "large";
  label: string;
  styling: string;
  type: string;
  callback?: () => void;
}

let main_btn = "bg-main text-white hover:bg-transparent hover:text-main";
let secondary_btn = "bg-transparent text-main hover:bg-main hover:text-white";

let sm = "py-[0.25rem] px-[0.5rem] text-sm";
let md = "py-[0.375rem] px-[0.75rem] text-base";
let lg = "py-[0.5rem] px-[0.1rem] text-lg";

const Button = ({
  primary = false,
  size = "medium",
  backgroundColor,
  label,
  type,
  styling,
  callback,
  ...props
}: ButtonProps) => {
  const mode = primary ? main_btn : secondary_btn;
  const sz = size === "medium" ? md : size === "small" ? sm : lg;

  function handleClick() {
    switch (type) {
      case "load":
        //When button has been clicked and processing takes a while add spinner
        break;
      case "disable":
        //If button is disabled for whatever reason add opacity
        break;
    }

    callback();
  }
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={`${sz} rounded ${mode} w-full text-center border border-main hover:cursor-pointer ${styling}`}
      style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor, borderColor: backgroundColor }}
      onClick={handleClick}
      {...props}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

app.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "./button.tsx"

export default function App() {

  function logIn() {
      console.log("Logging in....");
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button label="Iniciar sesión" primary={true} size="medium" styling="mb-8" type="load" onClick={logIn} />
    </div>
  );
}
```